# Replace Element in CKEditor Dialog after onShow Event

Tags: javascript, html, dialog, ckeditor, codemirror

I try to write an own plugin for CKEditor. The goal is to click a button in the toolbar that opens a dialog. In the dialog there is a `textArea` element that should be replaced by a CodeMirror instance.

I came so far that the dialog opens and I can grab the `textArea` and replace it. But it looks crappy and has no functionality. Furthermore there is no error in the console.

I can't figure out why that doesn't work.

`plugin.js` that starts when hitting my plugin button

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'abbr', {
    icons: 'abbr',
    init: function( editor ) {
        editor.addCommand( 'abbr',new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'abbrDialog' ) );

        // Create a toolbar button that executes the plugin command. 
        editor.ui.addButton( 'Abbr', {
            label: 'Insert SourceCode',
            command: 'abbr',
            toolbar: 'insert'
        } );

        CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'abbrDialog', function ( editor ) {
            return {
                title : 'Insert SourceCode',
                minWidth : 700,
                minHeight : 300,
                contents : [{
                        id : 'tab1',
                        label : 'label1',
                        elements :
                        [{
                            type : 'html',
                            html: '<textarea id="codeEditor"></textarea>',
                            id : 'codeEditor',
                            label : 'CodeEditor',
                        }]
                }],
                onShow : replacaByCodeMirror,
                onOk : saveActionFunc
            };
        });
    }
});

function replacaByCodeMirror() {
    var codeEditor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("codeEditor"), {
        mode : "mixedMode",
        theme : "default"
    });
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
        <script src="../plugins/codemirror/js/codemirror.js"></script></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../plugins/codemirror/css/codemirror.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../plugins/codemirror/css/myStyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                StartWort
            </textarea>
            <script>

                var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );

            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Screenshot: [Dialog Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrXgg.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run javascript code inside a ckeditor window (or within the ckeditor dialog box). The work around is to use an iframe inside the dialog box (there is an iframedialog plugin you have to add).

Answer (score 1):

That was exactly the info I needed. Thanks a lot! I would give you a vote but I have only 2 reputition.

Unfortunately there is almost no good example to find online. This helped me with it: [CKForum](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Iframe-dialog-height-iframe)